# Trying to create separate React component that accepts props and returns a dynamic Google search in a new window from those props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have most of the logic for this already. The issue I'm having is that I have two almost identical functions in two separate places of my app.

The logic takes a school name and the first and last name of an administrator and creates a google search link. That link is wrapped around the name of the administrator as an href and then executed when a user clicks the name, opening the search results in a new tab.

In the spirit of DRY and re usability I'm trying to extract the logic out and make it generic enough that I can pass the school and contact details in as props and generate the same link from anywhere in the app, but I'm stumped on how to do it.

My Component that I'm currently building is below along with the function in the app with similar logic.

`Component Being Built`

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from '../../styles/styled';
import { generateGoogleSearchLink } from '../google-search';


type Props = {
    children: React.ReactNode
  };

const GoogleSearch = (props: Props) => {

    const handleNameClick = (school, contact) => {
        if (!contact || !school) {
          return;
        }

        const url = generateGoogleSearchLink([
          contact.firstName,
          contact.lastName,
          contact.role,
          school.schoolName
        ]);
        window.open(url, '_blank');
      };


    return (
        <>
            <NameContainer onClick={() => handleNameClick(school, data.primaryContact)}>
                {children}
            </NameContainer>
        </>
    )
}

export default GoogleSearch

const NameContainer = styled('span')({
    color: '#676767',
    fontSize: '1em',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    textDecoration: 'underline'
  });
```

`Current Function logic`

```
return (
...
<>
  <NameContainer onClick={() => handleNameClick(school, data.primaryContact)}>
    {formatEmptyString(`${data.primaryContact.firstName} ${data.primaryContact.lastName}`)}
  </NameContainer>
</>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First things first, I'd advise you to stick to authentic HTML to the greatest extent possible; and use an anchor tag for this instead of a custom click event. So you would want to specify

```js
const NameContainer = styled('a')({
...
```

As a consequence, you would then need to render it as

```
<NameContainer to={{url}}>
```

where `url` is what you would generate with `generateGoogleSearchLink`, essentially some `https://google.com/search?q=john+doe+teacher+MIT`.

Aside from that I don't fully understand your issue? This seems generic?